# Can a Future throw an exception caught by a caller?

Tags: scala

When I run the code below it terminates and nothing happens, is there a way to catch the exception in `future2.map` ?

```
object TestFutures1 {
  val future1 = Future { 
    throw new Exception("error") 
    }
}

object TestFutures2 extends App {
  val future2 = TestFutures1.future1
  future2.map { result => println(result) }
  Thread.sleep(5000)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, there are two options (with some sub-options) to handle future exceptions.

1. You can add a callback that will be called when the future completes with an exception:

   ```
   future2
     .map { result => println(result) }
     .onFailure { exc => 
        exc.printStackTrace
     }
   ```

1a. `.onFailure` is only used for side effects, you cannot use, for example, to handle the exception. If you want to handle in and rescue the future, you can use `.recover` or `.recoverWith` (the only different between the two is that the latter takes a function that returns a `Future`, while the former deals with the actual result, same idea as `map` vs. `flatMap`:

```
    future2
      .map(println)
      .recover { case e => 
         e.printStackTrace
         "recovered"
      }.map(println)
```

2. The other option is to wait for the future to complete, and access it's result:

   ```
   try {
     // Instead of Thread.sleep - you don't need that:
     Await.result(future2, 2 seconds)
   } catch { case exc => 
     exc.printStackTrace
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Except @Dima's answer, also can use `onComplete` to catch failure, like:

```
  val re = future2.map { result => println(result) }
  re onComplete {
    case Success(s) => ...
    case Failure(e) => e.printStackTrace()
  }
```